# Using input fields instead of td, h3, o values in List.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, listjs

On the List.js site, they show how to use tables and even provide an example at http://www.listjs.com/examples/table.

```
<tr>
    <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg</td>
    <td class="born">1986</td>
</tr>
```

However, I want to use input values instead.

```
<tr>
    <input class="name" value="Jonny Stromberg">
    <input class="born" value="1986">
</tr>
```

The outcome is unexpected, with the input values rendering as empty. However, the ultimate goal is to give the input values names and save the columns/rows in a session. Has anyone been in the same boat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result using an input field and filling the value attribute. Here's a Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dEfjdNCi.

Notice that in "options" the class name points to the attribute "value."

```
<div id="users">
    <table>
        <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
        <tbody class="list">
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"><input class="id" type="hidden"></td>
            <td><input class="name"></td>
            <td><input class="born"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            valueNames: [
                {attr: 'value', name: 'id'},
                {attr: 'value', name: 'name'},
                {attr: 'value', name: 'born'},
            ]
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `<input>` in a `<td></td>` tag. You have set the `value` of the `<inputs>` tags correctly and so they should populate correctly.

Something like so worked fine for me:

```
<table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td><input class="name" value="Jonny Stromberg"></td>
        <td><input class="born" value="1986"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="name" value="Jonas Arnklint"></td>
        <td><input class="born" value="1985"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="name" value="Martina Elm"></td>
        <td><input class="born" value="1986"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="name" value="Gustaf Lindqvist"></td>
        <td><input class="born" value="1983"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/oLbey91h/1/

Comment: I thought I had tried that already but I'll try it again. Did you include the JS  script *after* the HTML?

Comment: @KarlHill Yep, in their examples they are using it after the `<table>` too. For all my apps, I pop the scripts just before my `</body>` tag.

Comment: Here's an example that doesn't seem to be working correctly, certainly not adding the new item in the list to the table. http://pastebin.com/A1vRJS5F

Comment: @KarlHill can you make a full example on JSFiddle or equivalent for me to see?

Comment: @KarlHill it works fine for me. See updated fiddle - it just doesn't populate the values in to an input field... https://jsfiddle.net/oLbey91h/3/ - note I had to add the class values back to the `<td>` to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Yes, this is exactly where I got to and why I got on StackOverflow. I need the values to populate an input field as the user will be changing the values on a large list. I've seen it where you can edit one record at a time but I need all the fields to be editable. It works for <textarea>{{ value }}</textarea> perhaps because the value is surrounded by tags. Disappointing.